# What is the idiomatic way to share an SQL connection between packages?

Tags: go

I usually declare a public `Db` variable in the main package

```
package main

var Db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error
    Db, err = sql.Open("sqlite3", BARS_FILE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer Db.Close()
    // passing Db as a parameter to other functions in other packages (database 
    // repositories) 

}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB it is safe to use sql.DB this way:

> DB is a database handle. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple
>   goroutines.

And IMHO it is ok to use it that way. Maybe later, when this variable becomes bottleneck you could create more handles. It could happen if a lot of gouroutines start using it. But do not optimize before it is necessary.